# Syntax Error в Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, build-error

Hашел этот [скрипт](https://github.com/giojzi/Simple_telegram_bot).

Но при запуске, он выдаёт синтаксическую ошибку. Я всего лишь изменил переменные токен и чат ид.   Помогите пожалуйста устранить эту ошибку что бы запустить бота, который будет отсылать периодические уведомления с определённым интервалом в чат-группу в телеграмм.

```
 user@q:~/mf/Downloads/Simple_telegram_bot$ cat chatbot1.py 

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import telegram
import time

def main():
    bot = telegram.Bot(token=971061211:AAGJvkc22wmN8O_6_0zw9rQJg4z_gUYsN0E)
    chat_id=-394356172
    message='hello world!' 
    interval=54
    while True:
        bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=message, parse_mode=telegram.ParseMode.HTML)
        time.sleep(interval)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()






user@q:~/mf/Downloads/Simple_telegram_bot$ python chatbot1.py 
  File "chatbot1.py", line 7
    bot = telegram.Bot(token=971061211:AAGJvkc22wmN8O_6_0zw9rQJg4z_gUYsN0E)
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
user@q:~/mf/Downloads/Simple_telegram_bot$ python3 chatbot1.py 
  File "chatbot1.py", line 7
    bot = telegram.Bot(token=971061211:AAGJvkc22wmN8O_6_0zw9rQJg4z_gUYsN0E)
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
user@q:~/mf/Downloads/Simple_telegram_bot$
```

Я попытался исправить, как советовали участники stackoverflow ниже, но получил такие ошибки.

Вариант исправления №1

```
user@drer:~/mf/Downloads/Simple_telegram_bot$ cat chatbot1.py 
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import telebot
import time

def main():
    bot=telebot.Telebot("token=971068318:AAEJvkc2cwmN8O_6_0Nw9RQJg7M_gUYsN0E")
    chat_id=-395376271
    message='TEST-HUEST!ALE-ALE-RODILSYA-YA' 
    interval=54
    while True:
        bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=message, parse_mode=telegram.ParseMode.HTML)
        time.sleep(interval)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()






user@drer:~/mf/Downloads/Simple_telegram_bot$ python chatbot1.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chatbot1.py", line 2, in <module>
    import telebot
ImportError: No module named telebot
```

**Вариант исправления №2**

```
user@q:~/mf/Downloads/Simple_telegram_bot$ cat chatbot2.py 
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import telegram
import time

def main():
    bot = telegram.Bot("token=971068318:AAEJvkc2cwmN8O_6_0Nw9RQJg7M_gUYsN0E")
    chat_id=-395376271
    message='TEST-HUEST!ALE-ALE-RODILSYA-YA' 
    interval=54
    while True:
        bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=message, parse_mode=telegram.ParseMode.HTML)
        time.sleep(interval)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()






user@q:~/mf/Downloads/Simple_telegram_bot$ python chatbot2.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chatbot2.py", line 2, in <module>
    import telegram
ImportError: No module named telegram
```

Скрипт должен отправлять однотипные автоматические уведомления с заданным интервалом времени в чат-группу телеграмм.

Comment: Токен возьмите в кавычки.

Comment: После того, как кавычки появились на своих местах, нужно установить зависимости. Команда в консоли `pip install python-telegram-bot` должна помочь преодолеть ошибку `No module named telegram`.

Comment: @insolor осталась та же ошибка. Я ещё попробовал так как посоветовали сделать ниже, но всё тщетно. Первое сообщение отредактировал

Comment: @mrEvgenX помогло.

Answer (score 0):

```
import telebot
import time

def main():    
    bot = telebot.Telebot("971061211:AAGJvkc22wmN8O_6_0zw9rQJg4z_gUYsN0E")
```

Comment: Та же ошибка осталась

Comment: а вы API телеграмма установили?